# Multiplication in F#

Tags: f#

I can't get my answer correctly from my multiplication function

My code is:

```
let List = [77; 14; 89; 93; 201]
    let rec Mult =
       match n with
       | 24 -> 24
       | _-> n * n
    for i = 1 to 5 do
       printfn "Multiplication: %A" (Mult i)
```

My question is how do I get I get it to call my List?

Comment: This pattern is often called `fold`. So you can do this to: `list |> List.fold ( * ) 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let List = [24; 103; 7; 13; 445]

let rec Mult = function
    | head :: tail -> head * (Mult tail)
    | [] -> 1

let result = Mult List
printfn "%A" result
```